# Is there a way to set the name an ArrayList returned by a Jersey Resource

Tags: java, rest, jersey

I have a method in a Jersey Web Service Resource which returns a ArrayList of objects

```
@GET
@Path("/GetMyObjects")
public List<MyObjectDTO> getMyObject() {
    List<MyObjectDTO> myObjects = new ArrayList<MyObjectDTO>();
    // ... fill the list ...
    return myObects;
}
```

This works but when the **ACCEPT** header is set to **application/xml** the root XML object which represents the ArrayList is `<myObjectDTOes>`.  I'm guessing the framework names the list by reflection of the parametrized type and applies some basic grammar rules to make it plural. My question is how can I override this to something like `<myObjectList>`

Thanks

Comment: Hey, Did you solve the issue? I have the same quesion.

Answer (score 3):

You can use [`@XmlRootElement(name="yourName")`](http://jersey.java.net/nonav/documentation/latest/xml.html#d4e820) on your POJO to name the returning XML elements in Jersey response.

**Update based on the first comment**

As far as I know the best way to resolve this issue with Jersey + JAXB is to define a wrapper class which sounds like unnecessary duplication:

```
@XmlRootElement(name="yourName")
class JaxbCollectionWrapper<T> {

  private Collection<T> objects;

  @XmlElement(name="singleObjectName")
  public Collection<T> getObjects() {/* BLAH */}

}
```

Also note that `@XmlElementWrapper` cannot be used with Jersey.

If you'd be using RESTEasy, there is a direct solution that can provide what you want; `@Wrapped` which is described [here](http://docs.jboss.org/resteasy/docs/2.0.0.GA/userguide/html_single/index.html#JAXB_Collections).

Comment: Yes this works if I return only one object.  But when I am returning an ArrayList of this POJO, the root element is the ArrayList so I cannot add an annotation to that class.  My question is if there is a way to programmatically set the root element name when building the ArrayList

Comment: The answer is updated based on what I understood and know about this issue.